# Sharing functions across multiple files in C and managing compilation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, gcc, g++, include, vscode-debugger

I'm currently working on a C project in Visual Studio Code where I need to share functions across multiple files. Initially, I encountered errors related to updating the include path when using `**#include "filename.h"**`. After some research and troubleshooting, I managed to resolve this issue by configuring the *tasks.json* file to include individual files using `${fileDirname}/filename.c` (Edited the **args** variable in the `tasks.json` configuration file to include individual file paths for compilation.).

However, I have a couple of concerns regarding this approach:

When I compile my project, does this mean that compilation runs for each file listed in `tasks.json` on every build?
Is it necessary to explicitly list all files in my project in `tasks.json`, or is there a more efficient way to manage compilation for projects with multiple files?
I want to ensure that I'm managing compilation efficiently and avoiding unnecessary errors. Additionally, I'm curious if there are alternative methods or best practices for managing include paths and sharing functions between files in C projects using Visual Studio Code.

Any guidance or insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: "_When I compile my project, does this mean that compilation runs for each file listed in tasks.json on every build?_"

Yes. If you don't want unnecessary recompilation of source files, then you should look into using a buildsystem, but I'd highly recommend learning CMake (a buildsystem generator). VS Code has integration for CMake through the CMake Tools extension. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75093720/11107541, and https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77979031/why-do-people-hate-cmake-and-why-hasnt-a-better-cmake-taken-its-place

Comment: "_Is it necessary to explicitly list all files in my project in tasks.json, or is there a more efficient way to manage compilation for projects with multiple files?_"

If you're going to use a simple build task with no buildsystem, then yes. Again, I recommend a buildsystem. Heads up that many buildsystems' configuration systems will force or highly recommend you to list source files manually. That includes CMake.

Comment: the rest of your question touches on a somewhat deep topic, and you should avoid asking multiple questions in a single question post (see [/help/dont-ask](/help/dont-ask))